# Unable to start web2py

Tags: python-3.x, web2py

I installed Web2py on my machine. When I click web2py.exe, a console appears for a second and disappears. Nothing more than that. What must be missing?

Comment: Open a command line and start the program from there. You might be able to see some error messages then

Comment: C:\myproject\web2py_win\web2py>web2py.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "__main__.py", line 128, in <module>
  File "__main__web2py__.py", line 33, in <module>
TypeError: start() takes no arguments (1 given)

C:\myproject\web2py_win\web2py>

Answer (score 1):

As per different blog post, the latest web2py version is broken. You can download an older version from the the for the time being. For my case, I am now started with a older version.

[Download older version from here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/UdF_UNZB1mQ)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be broken.  However, you can download the source and run it like this:

```
python web2py.py
```

There's a [discussion mentioning the problem](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/web2py/jIFto8ry1JE/IoXTy_oyCAAJ) on the web2py group and Nico Zanferrari has a [fix in his repository](https://github.com/nicozanf/web2py-pyinstaller).